# NodeJS Websocket Postman connection prevents node process from exiting when restarting server

Tags: node.js, express, websocket, nestjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using NestJS to create my websocket server using the [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) library on WSL2. Here are the following steps to reproduce my issue:

- I run my HTTP server with `nest start`
- I connect to the ws instance using Postman
- I shut down the server process in my terminal with "Ctrl + C"
- Postman says I'm still connected to the server

If I run the server again, I get a `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000` which requires me to manually kill the process.

I can also disconnect from postman and then I'll be able to start the server again. This seems really weird to me and I don't remember this happening when working with a regular Express app ws server.

I guess I should be terminating all client connections when the server is closed, but I thought this was supposed to automatically happen. Am I missing something here?

Edit: I tried building my NestJS app and ran `node main.js` in my /dist directory. And now it's properly handling disconnecting all clients when closing the server. Issues seems to be related to using the nest cli?

Comment: getting the same issue on plain express